# Replace uri with property from configuration file in xml

Tags: java, xml, spring, apache-camel

How can I replace the uri with the text from configuration file `myprops.cfg`?

```
<route id="camel-http-proxy2">
   <from uri="jetty://http://127.0.0.1:5555/mock"/>
</route>
```

myprops.cfg:

```
myuri=http://127.0.0.1:555/mock
```

my try:

```
<route id="camel-http-proxy2">
   <from uri="jetty://${myuri}"/>
</route>
```

Then the camel read the uri as it is, it doesnt replace it with the value of the property.
another try:

```
<endpoint id="input1" uri="jetty//${myuri}"/>

<route id="camel-http-proxy2">
  <from uri="ref:input1"/>
</route>
```

error:

> org.osgi.service.blueprint.container.ComponentDefinitionException: Unable to validate xml
>   org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element '{"http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint":endpoint}'. One of '{"http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint":route}' is expected.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is:

```
<route id="camel-http-proxy2">
  <from uri="jetty://{{myuri}}"/>
</route>
```

The documentation of camel is not updated I think.

Comment: If you have found something outdated on https://camel.apache.org/ website. Can you please use `Edit this Page` link in top right corner on that page and fix this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the config file within the property-placeholder tag.

```
<cm:property-placeholder id="myblueprint.placeholder" persistent-id="myprops">
```

You can then reference the property as `${properties:myuri}` or `{{myuri}}`